# Malloc not allocating space

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc

I am trying to write a C program that reads input from a file dynamically. The data in the input file is not in fixed columns, they are separated with ':'. I am reading each line from input file and passing to the following function for split based on ':', and return an array of strings. Defined char **stringArray to return the list of strings to the main program. But my program is stopping in the malloc step below, without throwing any error.

Can someone point out what's the issue with this space allocation?

```
char **splitString(char *inputString, char delim)
{
    int cur_size=100,i=0;
    char **stringArray;
    printf("in splitstring, input read : %s\n",inputString);
    if (NULL==(stringArray=(char **)malloc(cur_size*sizeof(char *)))){
        fprintf(stderr,"%s","Error while allocating space while split string");
    }
    printf("%s\n","in splitstring, space allocated");
    return stringArray;
}
```

input file :

```
XX1701:x:11701:601:Name 1:/folder1/subfolder/subsubfolder1:/bin/bash
XX1702:x:11702:601:Name 2 Title:/folder1/subfolder/subsubfolder 2:/bin/bash
XX1703:x:11703:601:Name 3 Title 3:/folder1/subfolder/subsubfolder3:/bin/bash
```

Output from the program, I am getting:

```
$ ./sortStudent
In main , input read : XX1701:x:11701:601:Name 1:/folder1/subfolder/subsubfolder1:/bin/bash
in splitstring, input read : XX1701:x:11701:601:Name 1:/folder1/subfolder/subsubfolder1:/bin/bash
$
```

Main :

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char *inputLine, **inputSplit;
    FILE *fptr;
    char *filename = "studentInput.txt";
    int allocated_size=100,i,j,rc=0;

    if (NULL == (fptr= fopen(filename,"r"))){ // Opens file in read mode and checks file open error
        fprintf(stderr,"\nError in opening file %s",filename);
        return -1;
    }

    if (NULL==(inputLine=(char *)calloc(1000,sizeof(char)))){
        fprintf(stderr,"%s\n","Error in calloc");
        return -1;
    }

    while (NULL!=fptr){
        rc=getInput(fptr, &inputLine, '\n');
        if (-1==rc){
            return -1;
        }
        if (1==rc){
            break;
        }
        printf("In main , input read : %s\n",inputLine);
        inputSplit = splitString(inputLine, ':');
        printf("In main, input split : %s %s %s\n",inputSplit[0],inputSplit[2],inputSplit[4]);
     return 0;
}
```

getinput:

```
int getInput(FILE * filePointer, char **storeStr,char endChar)
{
    int i=0,c,cur_size=1;
    if(NULL==(*storeStr = (char *)malloc(cur_size*sizeof(char)))){
        fprintf(stderr,"%s","Error in malloc inside getInput function");
        return -1;
    }
    if (EOF==(c=fgetc(filePointer))){
        return 1;
    }
    (*storeStr)[i]=c;
    for (i=1;EOF!=(c=fgetc(filePointer)) && (c)!=endChar;i++){ // Read next character from input until end string is reached

        if ((i+1) <= cur_size){
            cur_size *=2;
            if(NULL==(*storeStr = (char *)realloc(*storeStr,cur_size))){
                fprintf(stderr,"%s","Error in realloc inside getInput function");
                return -1;
            }
        }
        (*storeStr)[i]=c;
    }

    (*((*storeStr)+i))='\0';    // Add null char to denote end of string
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include a `main` function (and any other supporting functions) so we can get a complete picture of what you're doing.

Comment: "*program is stopping in the malloc step*" That's unlikely. How did you determine that?

Comment: @dxiv: The print statement just before malloc, is shown in output, the print just after malloc, is not shown at output.

Comment: @dbush: Added all details.

Comment: @SuktiSen 1) `inputSplit = splitString(...` This sets `inputSplit` to point to an array of `100` *uninitialized* pointers. 2) `printf("In main, input split : %s ...` This attempts to print some of those uninitialized pointers, which results in [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

Comment: @dxiv: I am taking care of the infinite loop with checking (1==rc){  break;}, rc is the return code of getInput(), when EOF reached. Also **inputSplit is initialised inside splitString(), its referred to as char **stringArray inside splitString().

Comment: @SuktiSen If you refer to `stringArray=(char **)malloc(cur_size*sizeof(char *))` then that allocates the array of `100` pointers, but there is no code in `splitString` that initializes any of those `100` pointers, so they are all left at garbage values. That means, as I wrote, that `inputSplit = splitString(...` sets `inputSplit` to point to an array of `100` uninitialized pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory allocation errors typically don't manifest at the point the error happened but at some later time.  That's what happened here.

In `getInput` you perform this check to see if you need to expand your buffer:

```
if ((i+1) <= cur_size){
```

As it's written, you only expand the buffer if the current index is *smaller* than the capacity instead of larger.  So on the first iteration you write past the end of allocated memory.

You instead want:

```
if ((i+1) >= cur_size){
```

Also, you're not setting the members of `stringArray` in `splitString` so you need to add code to populate those.